# Conda doesn't work in Vertex AI deeplearning images

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, conda

When provisioning a VM on GCS with a single T4 GPU and Tensorflow conda doesn't work correctly. I can't create new virtual environments or install any packages.

```
$ conda info


active environment : base
active env location : /opt/conda
shell level : 1
user config file : /home/plateu/.condarc
populated config files : /opt/conda/.condarc
conda version : 4.11.0
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.7.12.final.0
virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                  __linux=4.19.0=0
                  __glibc=2.28=0
                  __unix=0=0
                  __archspec=1=x86_64
base environment : /opt/conda  (writable)
conda av data dir : /opt/conda/etc/conda
conda av metadata url : None
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs
               /home/plateu/.conda/pkgs
envs directories : /opt/conda/envs
               /home/plateu/.conda/envs
platform : linux-64
user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.7.12 Linux/4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 debian/10 glibc/2.28
UID:GID : 1002:1003
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

Trying out the conda installation

```
$ conda create --name fm37 python=3.7.12

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
   path: /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/18414ddb.json
   uid: 1002
   gid: 1003

 If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
 change them by executing

 $ sudo chown 1002:1003 /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/18414ddb.json

 In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

Following the advise from conda:

```
$ sudo chown 1002:1003 /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/18414ddb.json

chown: cannot access '/opt/conda/pkgs/cache/18414ddb.json': No such file or directory
```

I really need to be able to create virtual envs in this VM as I SSH into it using VSCode and can't access any ipykernels from vscode unless they are in a conda env.

```
$ sudo /opt/conda/bin/conda create --name fm37 python=3.7.12

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/conda/envs/fm37

  added / updated specs:
     - python=3.7.12
   
  ..... etc.
```

So that works but only rudimentary. I get major problems using VSCode and I need to reinstall Tensorflow which was in the base environment, so should also be in any other environment.